# How to pass list of IDs from one Oracle schema to another?

Tags: sql, oracle

I use the Oracle SQL developer to query the Oracle database

So, my simplified script is as follows:

```
alter session set current_schema=schema1;
select id from table1

alter session set current_schema=schema2;
select * from table2 where remote_id in (<the list from the 1st query in schema1>)
```

Currently I copy the list from one schema to another manually.  How to automate passing the list?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fully qualified database object references in Oracle are `SCHEMANAME.OBJECTNAME` so regardless of which schema is your current schema, you can reference objects in other schemas like so:

```
Select *
  from schema2.table2
 where remote_id in (select id from schema1.table1);
```

Comment: With addition that - in such a query - SCHEMA1 has to `GRANT SELECT ON TABLE1 TO SCHEMA2` (or vice versa, depending on who selects from whose table).

Comment: Since the OP was switching parsing schemas with `alter session set current_schema` I assumed he already had select privileges granted to his login schema

Comment: I'm not complaining, just saying.